# Phonegap fullscreen (title and navigation)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am using a Motorola Moto G Android device. If I run a Phonegap App with `fullscreen=false` the app shows the title bar (battery, carrier, ...) and at the bottom a navigation bar (back, hide app, ..). In `fullscreen=true` both bars disappear. Other Android and iOS devices probably don't have this bottom navigation bar.

Now a few doubts:

- Even in `fullscreen=true` during the splash screen the navigation bar at the bottom is shown and disappears only when the splash screen hides. How can I hide the bottom navigation bar during the splash screen?
- In another case I want to hide only the top title bar but show the navigation bar always. Is that possible?